# How to get the (localized) day of the week lowercased in time-stamp-format?

Tags: time-date

The `%:a` allows to get the full weekday in the Time-stamp. My `system-time-locale` is `fr_FR.UTF-8`. I am using the Time-stamp in a Markdown file, inside a [pandoc title block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-pandoc_title_block), which I export to html, so I can then use the so created pandoc `date` variable in suitable html template.

I use a prefix  `dernière mise à jour le`, (meaning `last update on`), hence according to French orthographic rules I need for example `lundi`, not `Lundi`.

Is there anyway to set-up `time-stamp-format` to produce a lowercase full week of the day? I see only `%:a` which however produces like in English week days with first letter uppercased.

Comment: I approved addition of `org-mode` tag, but let me point out I am using directly `time-stamp-format`, `time-stamp-start`, `time-stamp-end` as Local Variables in a buffer whose major mode is `Markdown`.

Comment: When I went looking for `time-stamp-format`, I only found `org-time-stamp-format` to be defined in my own Emacs, so that's why I added the tag. Only later I saw the docs for `time-stamp-format`. Regarding your question, I do not think it is possible to get a lower-case date using only `time-stamp-format`.

Comment: @Arnot thanks for the `org-mode` tag and time you spent on this, I explained the background only to clarify `-;)` Well, I am sad to hear about not there being escape here. If I could leave the time-stamp on its line, encapsulated sort-of in some e-Lisp expression so that say on next line the week-day is "corrected" that could solve my problem.

Comment: @Arnot @jfbu In the context of this question, `time-stamp-format` is unrelated to `org-mode`. `format-time-string` is relevant because it is a subroutine of `time-stamp`. Thus the question is more about locales and how to customise them, in particular w.r.t. letter case.

Comment: @Basil there is a `localization` tag, would it be appropriate here? (it has no description)

Comment: I briefly considered adding the `localization` tag, but I think the description of `time-date` covers this question completely.